# Trouble with Wordpress local development and deployments

Tags: wordpress, amazon-web-services, deployment, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, w3-total-cache

**The Setup:**

I'm setting up a Wordpress-powered application using Elastic Beanstalk from Amazon Web Services. All development is being done locally under a MAMP apache2/php5 server environment with a GIT repository controlling the entire application root.

**Deployment Workflow:**

After committing any code changes (edits, new plugins, etc) to the repo the application is deployed using AWS EB CLI's `eb deploy` command which pushes the latest version out to any running EC2 instances managed by Elastic Beanstalk.

**My Issue:**

Sometimes the code changes aren't exactly syncing up between my development/production environments and I'm not sure how to overcome it. Especially when trying to install and setup plugins like W3 Total Cache or WP Super Cache.

Since my local environment doesn't have things like a memcahced server installed, but my production environment does (ElastiCache) I'm unable to save the proper settings file and deploy it for use in my production environment. These plugins won't allow me to select the needed services because it sees them as not available...

It seems I can only get W3 Total Cache to work if I install it directly onto a live production environment, which seems like a bad idea.

**Given the above:**

- Am I going about deployments the wrong way?
- Should plugins like W3 Total Cache be installed and configured on
  local development environments and pushed to production environments?

Comment: what exactly is the question here? what doesn't work?

Comment: @tal I just isolated the questions for more clarity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I cannot comment on the issues specific to Elastic Beanstalk, but based on experience I can make a suggestion about the second part of your issue statement:

You are better off running a development environment that mirrors your production environment as closely as possible. I suggest that you convert from MAMP to a VM environment like VirtualBox. You might want to check out puphpet.com for help in getting it set up. It requires some startup effort, but gives you an environment similar to or the same as your production servers. For example, you could run memcached yourself so you could actually test it with W3 Total Cache.

As for your second question, just installing a plugin in the production environment without testing it beforehand has obvious risks (but then again clients do that all the time). I would prefer to test first. To a certain extent it probably depends on how critical it is if the site experiences downtime or weirdness.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I actually came across Vagrant as an alternate to MAMP and started playing around with it yesterday. It looks like it'll be some work getting the dev env to match what AWS Elastic Beanstalk spins up, but you're right, a VM is the way to go.

Comment: Yes, Vagrant is very helpful. I still recommend that you look at phphpet. It is essentially a frontend for Vagrant. It lets you choose a bunch of options and then creates the Vagrant configuration files so that "vagrant up" does what you want. I believe that Beanstalk is even handled by puphpet.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you to create another environment on Beanstalk.
It's easy, fast and more reliable than a VM in your case because it will allow you to test your deployment process as well.

I usually have 3 environment for a every website. Each environment is on its own branch. If your configuration is different between environment (url and database access for example), just store your wp-config and other config files into S3 (you may not want production password in your git repository), and through ebextensions you can download them into your website automatically.

I use AWS Beanstalk that way for 16 websites and some are wordpress one. All with autoscaling and able to get thousands of users simultaneously.

Don't hesitate to ask me for further details.